# HTML5 Sound plugin?

Tags: jquery, html, audio, jquery-plugins, html5-audio

Currently I'm using [soundmanager2](/questions/tagged/soundmanager2) to power sounds in my web app. SoundManager uses Flash, which sometimes crashes, killing sounds. Is there a reliable plugin available in jQuery that powers sounds using HTML5 rather than with Flash?

**My Settings:**

```
soundManager.url = '/misc/soundmanager2/v20111220/';    // SoundManager fails if the SWF is loaded from the CDN
soundManager.debugMode = true;
soundManager.flashVersion = 9;
soundManager.useFlashBlock = false;
soundManager.useHTML5Audio = true;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SoundManager can also play pure HTML5 sound.

> SoundManager 2 gives you a single, powerful API that supports both new and old, using HTML5 audio where supported and optional Flash-based fallback where needed. Ideally when using SoundManager 2, audio "just works."

Flash is only (**optionally**) used as fallback. Or for some nifty stuff which isn't (very well) supported (yet) by all browsers. Like a spectrum analyzer etc.

To 'force' SoundManager2 to use HTML5 audio you can add the following parameter:

```
soundManager.preferFlash = false;
```

> overrides useHTML5audio. if true and flash support present, will try to use flash for MP3/MP4 as needed since HTML5 audio support is still quirky in browsers.

From the [official docs](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/doc/).

Comment: Thanks, I've been trying to use SoundManager with html5 set to true in Chrome. However it still loads the swf.

Comment: @AnApprentice what version are you using?

Comment: I'm using the latest version. IN debug mode I get the following error. Perhaps html5 doesn't like mp3? "-- SoundManager 2: HTML5 support tests (/^(probably|maybe)$/i): mp3: true (preferring flash), mp4: true (preferring flash), ogg: true, wav: true --"

Comment: @AnApprentice are you sure you aren't setting: `soundManager.preferFlash = true;`? Also note `overrides useHTML5audio. if true and flash support present, will try to use flash for MP3/MP4 as needed since HTML5 audio support is still quirky in browsers.`. From [the docs](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/doc/).

Comment: @HoeHoeHoe just edited by Q adding my settings. How does that look? If html5 was working, would the swf still be loaded?

Comment: @AnApprentice what happens if you add `soundManager.preferFlash = false;`?

Comment: @AnApprentice Glad I could help you out. I'll also add the solution into my answer for others to see.

Answer (score 2):

#### Description

I suggest **jPlayer**.

> **jPlayer is the completely free and open source** (GPL/MIT) media library written in JavaScript. A **jQuery plugin**, jPlayer allows you to rapidly weave cross platform audio and video into your web pages. jPlayer's comprehensive API allows you to create innovative media solutions while support and encouragement is provided by jPlayer's active and growing community.

#### Sample

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
  ready: function () {
   $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
    m4a: "/media/mysound.mp4",
    oga: "/media/mysound.ogg"
   });
  },
  swfPath: "/js",
  supplied: "m4a, oga"
 });
});
```

#### More Information

- [jPlayer - The jQuery HTML5 Audio / Video Library](http://jplayer.org/)

Comment: i second this recommendation.. i've never had issues with the Flash fallback crashing in jPlayer..

Answer (score 1):

Use the HTML5 Audio tag as shown in this [link](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/audio/quick/).

Answer (score 0):

i've released an audio player framework that leverages SoundManager2 AND integrates w/ jQuery as a $.fn. -- very simple to use and/or customize.. similar to jPlayer in the front-end design, but w/ additional playback capabilities (eg RTMP streaming, full HTML5 support), examples, tests etc:

https://github.com/APMG/APMPlayer